# Keep a application window always on current desktop on linux and mac

Tags: c++, qt, gnome, kde-plasma

I search a way to put a QWidget window of a Qt application always on the current desktop/workspace.
When I change the virtual desktop, I need my window to be automatically visible on the new current virtual desktop.

I search a solution that works at minimum on gnome, kde on linux and mac os.

I think the first step is to detect when virtual desktop is change, I don't know if Qt have a API for that or if I need to implement it for each desktop solution.

Comment: I do hope you have good reason for doing this as this could end up being very annoying if an application starts chasing me across my desktops. The main reason I use Virtual desktop's is to have "different" windows on each.

Comment: It's a small transparent widget to remember your actual task and need to be always visible for never forget the actual task (like a companion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Jan Kundrát for his help (Previous comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/16777496/1045832 ).

Solution for linux X11 :

```
#ifdef Q_WS_X11 //only define on Qt 4.X 
#include <QX11Info> //Only on Qt 4.X , return expected in Qt 5.1
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#endif

YourWidget::YourWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::YourWidget)
{

#ifdef Q_WS_X11 //only define on Qt 4.X 
    unsigned long data = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    XChangeProperty (QX11Info::display(),
                     winId(),
                     XInternAtom(QX11Info::display(), "_NET_WM_DESKTOP", False),
                     XA_CARDINAL,
                     32,
                     PropModeReplace,
                     reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data), // all desktop
                     1);
#endif
}
```

Put this on your .pro

```
unix:!macx {
    LIBS += -lX11
}
```

Solution for macos X :

```
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>

WId windowObject = this->winId();
objc_object * nsviewObject = reinterpret_cast<objc_object *>(windowObject);
objc_object * nsWindowObject = objc_msgSend(nsviewObject, sel_registerName("window"));
int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces = 1 << 0;
objc_msgSend(nsWindowObject, sel_registerName("setCollectionBehavior:"), NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces);
```

Put this on your .pro

```
macx {
    LIBS += -lobjc
}
```

Comment: Looks like `data` is a private member of QWidget and cannot be accessed by subclasses.

Comment: `error: no matching function for call to 'objc_msgSend' […] note: candidate function not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 2 were provided` Note arm64 Macbook Air.

Answer (score 4):

Under X11, you are supposed to [set the `_NET_WM_DESKTOP` window property to `0xFFFFFFFF`](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.4/ar01s05.html). I suspect there's no Qt API for that, so you'll have to litter the code with `#ifdef`s checking for X11 and call an appropriate X's function (nope, I don't know which one it is).

Comment: Thanks you Jan for your help. I will try to use XChangeProperty ( X11/Xlib.h ) to setup the windows property and QX11Info present in Qt4.8 and QT5.1 to have access to X11 data from . I will post the solution when I have finished.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working example for MacOS 12 and M1 chip

```
WId windowObject = this->winId();
objc_object * nsviewObject = reinterpret_cast<objc_object *>(windowObject);

objc_object * nsWindowObject = ((objc_object* (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(nsviewObject, sel_registerName("window"));

int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace = 1 << 1;
int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient = 1 << 3;
int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary = 1 << 8;
int total = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace
        |NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient
        | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary;

((objc_object* (*)(id, SEL, int))objc_msgSend)(nsWindowObject, sel_registerName("setCollectionBehavior:"), total);
```

[Found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69778258/)