# Keeping a window on the active OS X desktop

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt, window-managers

In OS X Mission Control, a user can create multiple desktops.

If a system message appears, such as a request for authentication when clicking on a padlock in System Preferences, the message dialog will always be visible when the user switches desktop; the message dialog moves to the active desktop.

How can I create the same behaviour with my own dialog. Currently I have an application in Qt with a message dialog based on QDialog.

Using Qt is preferrable, but if this is not possible with Qt, how would one go about doing this with a native objective-c (Cocoa) window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the window flag `Qt::Popup` it should display on the active desktop space, it's how QMessageBox works IIRC and that definitely displays on the active desktop space.

Edit; https://stackoverflow.com/a/16882717/741595 shows how to do it using the Cocoa bridge.

Comment: No, that doesn't work. It simply removes the title bar and still fails to move to the active desktop as I switch desktops. I can get the dialog to come up on the current active desktop, but I need it to move as the active desktop changes.