# PyQt5 application visible in all cinnamon/gnome workspaces

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to have an application written in `pyqt5` always visible in all the `cinnamon/gnome` virtual work spaces.
**Example:** `'conky'`
But investigating `QDesktopApplication`, `QWindow` and `QScreen` doesn't seem to be the right way. Any address please?

**Edit**: I had already seen the answer at [Keep a application window always on current desktop on linux and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775352) and it is a C++ answer but my question is about `pyQt5`. It seems that the direction is to work with a kind of C++ wrapper.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep a application window always on current desktop on linux and mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775352/keep-a-application-window-always-on-current-desktop-on-linux-and-mac)

Comment: There is no way to do this using pyqt5. You'll have to use ctypes to set the `_NET_WM_DESKTOP` hint, or use a third-party package that does the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks to @ekhumoro for the address

Answer (score 0):

In the following code a simple text box is visualized on all workspaces.
This is possible using the python-ewmh package to set the _NET_WM_DESKTOP hint at 0xffffffff.

```
"""
  example.py

  simple widget on bottom level visible in all workspaces
"""


import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from ewmh import EWMH


class Panel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """ main panel """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Panel, self).__init__()

        # panel size and position
        self.setFixedSize(300, 200)                     # width, height
        self.move(100, 100)                             # x, y

        # panel flags
        flags = QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint           # no border and no title bar
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint      # always on bottom level
        flags |= QtCore.Qt.Tool                         # no icon on taskbar
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)

        # panel style
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.8)                      # 0=transparent; 1=opaque
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color:#334455;padding: 0;margin: 0;")

        # text label
        txt = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        txt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        txt.setStyleSheet("background:transparent;color:#000000;font:40px;padding:0;margin:0;")
        txt.setText('Hello world!')

        # vertical layout
        v_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        v_layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        v_layout.setSpacing(0)
        v_layout.addWidget(txt)
        self.setLayout(v_layout)

        # show the panel
        self.show()

        # show the panel in all workspaces
        # (taken from ewmh documentation)
        ewmh = EWMH()
        all_wins = ewmh.getClientList()
        wins = filter(lambda w: w.get_wm_class()[1] == 'example.py', all_wins)
        for w in wins:
            ewmh.setWmDesktop(w, 0xffffffff)
        ewmh.display.flush()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    p = Panel()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```