# How to make Qt app visible on top on all screens?

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa

How can I make a Qt window (keyboard launcher) show up on all spaces like e.g. Spotlight or iterm2 hotkey window.

I need to achieve the following: The launcher window has to be able to show up on every screen, even full screen apps, no dock item, not window switcher item, no main menu, this should work without any further implications (see below). Nice to have would be if the settings window would be still a regular window.

I tried to use `qputenv("QT_MAC_DISABLE_FOREGROUND_APPLICATION_TRANSFORM", "1");` but using this the window accepts no keyboard input anymore. I also tried

```cpp
WId windowObject = this->winId();
objc_object * nsviewObject = reinterpret_cast<objc_object *>(windowObject);

objc_object * nsWindowObject = ((objc_object* (*)(id, SEL))objc_msgSend)(nsviewObject, sel_registerName("window"));

int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace = 1 << 1;
int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient = 1 << 3;
int NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary = 1 << 8;
int total = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorMoveToActiveSpace
        |NSWindowCollectionBehaviorTransient
        | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary;

((objc_object* (*)(id, SEL, int))objc_msgSend)(nsWindowObject, sel_registerName("setCollectionBehavior:"), total);
```

but this way the window does not show over fullscreen apps and also has still a dock item and main menu.

Comment: what is `objc_object` ?  it seems this is part of the code . please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objc_object I cant tell. I have virtually any clue of cocoa and objc. I just copied this snipped from the web. The problem is that it is a c++ unit and makes use of the ability to cast objc type into C.